# Pause animation onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that goes through each div on the page that has a `data-slides` property which specifies some images to display. It animates the different images in a loop by fading them in and out:

```
(function($) {
'use strict';
 $('[data-slides]').each(function(){ 
        var $slides = $(this);
        var images = $slides.data('slides');
        var count = images.length;
        var number = 0;
        var slideshow = function() {
            $slides
                .css('background-image', 'url("' + images[number%count] + '")')
                .show(0, function() {
                    setTimeout(slideshow, 3500);
                });
                number++;
        };
        
        slideshow();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

What I want to do is have a button that pauses a specific element that's animating, and then another button which starts its slideshow animation again. How can I do that?

### Edit

Using a suggestion from Flash Thunder, I've updated it with a separate timer which can be paused:

```
function Timer(callback, delay) {
    var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

    this.pause = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        remaining -= new Date() - start;
   };

   this.resume = function() {
        start = new Date();
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    };

    this.resume();
}

function runSlideshow(div){ 
    var $slides = div;
    var images = $slides.data('slides');
    var count = images.length;
    var number = 0;
    this.slideshow = function() {
        $slides
            .css('background-image', 'url("' + images[number%count] + '")')
            .show(0, function() {
                timer.resume();
            });
            number++;
    };
    var timer = new Timer(this.slideshow, 3500);
    
    this.slideshow();
}

(function($) {
    'use strict';
     $('[data-slides]').each(function() {
            var run = new runSlideshow($(this));
            run.slideshow();
     });
}(jQuery));
```

This works, however, I need to be able to access the timer from any of the `$('[data-slides]')` to be able to pause it. How can I?

Comment: can you add your HTML it might get easier to add a snippet with running example with the fix you want

Answer (score 0):

```
function Timer(callback, delay) {
    var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

    this.pause = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        remaining -= new Date() - start;
    };

    this.resume = function() {
        start = new Date();
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    };

    this.resume();
}

var timer = new Timer(function() {
    alert("Done!");
}, 1000);

timer.pause();
// Do some stuff...
timer.resume();
```

Credits to [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down).

Comment: Do you think you could tailor this to my code? I'm not a native JS developer so I'm not quite sure how this relates.

Comment: Add this function to your code, use `timer` with same parameters instead of `setTimeout`, and then you can call `timer.pause()` and `timer.resume()` wherever you like. For example in `onclick` event.

Comment: Ok cool I've managed to do that. However, how do I access the timer from a separate onclick event? Because I've run a foreach loop over the elements it seems hard to access it. I've updated my code...

Comment: to set it global, define it as `window.timer` instead of `var timer` in line `var timer = new Timer(function() { ...` - should be `window.timer = new Timer(function() { ...`... then it will be accessible as `timer` or `window.timer` in every place

Comment: I don't want there to be just one global timer though, I want separate timers for each `$('[data-slides]')` element that I can individually control.